# Can anyone tell me what this jacket says (Characters identified: 盖世英雄)

Tags: character-identification, writing

[image: jacket with either Chinese or Japanese writing on it]

Help i have a jacket here that I want to buy but I need to know what it says and the site does not provide that information

Comment: The symbol with the circle and arrow seems to add a slightly different meaning to the phrase, but I am not exactly sure what it is meant to imply.

Answer (score 4):

read right to left, top to bottom:

盖世：gài​shì：unrivalled
英雄: yīng​xióng: hero

Comment: It's also the Chinese name of the game "Final Heroes," the name of a TV show called "Heroes of Remix," and also the name of a film, "Matchless Hero." I'm sure the clothing is not specifically referring to any of those though.

Answer (score -1):

The circle with an arrow makes no sense to me. However, I think 盖世英雄 is used to refer to 项羽, who was the number one hero at his time but was defeated by 刘邦 who had a low beginning, and was not considered very righteous, but who made the first emperor of Han dynasty.

Comment: Could the circle with an arrow circling 世, (meaning "world"), implies the present ascendancy of the feminine principle in our modern era and the "arrow" pointing at 英, (bravery) indicates a brave new world for females, (given the increasing number of females with high political power at present?) Also the circle with a downward pointing arrow is same as the symbol for female.